# How do I install a meteor js project downloaded from the internet?

Tags: javascript, meteor

So I downloaded an old project from github, however, since I don't have a local copy anymore, how can I make it runnable on meteor?

```
meteor npm install
```

Doesn't work since there's no .meteor or node modules.

Comment: Which version of Meteor did it run on? Is it a public github repo? If you have the .meteor folder it will tell you which version of meteor, and should therefore run "out of the box"

Comment: 1.4, but since it's a public repo no .meteor

Comment: if it's fairly recent (1.4) then it shouldn't be too bad to get going, you'll just need to try and work out what meteor and npm packages are loaded. Just because it's a public repo, doesn't mean that the .meteor folder couldn't be checked  in

Comment: can we get more details as to what you tried? also if the rep is public you might want to link it in your question?

Comment: can you share exactly what error messages are shown?